# Aplicar Estilos a un Datalist en las opciones

Tags: html5, html5-datalist

tengo este problema, tengo un input el cual con tiene un datalist:

```
<input id="EmplName" runat="server" 
list="listEmpl" oninput='onInput()' 
placeholder="All Employee" />       
<datalist id="listEmpl" runat="server" />
```

Ahora quiero saber si puedo aplicarle un css al Datalist, en otros sitios me dicen que aplique estilos al input pero es no es lo que necesito, si alguien sabe si se puede o no gracias

Comment: Lo siento, pero actualmente no existe la posibilidad de aplicarle estilos a un `datalist` de manera convencional. Puedes leer [esta discusión](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13693859/9609518) en el sitio original de SO.

Comment: Que mal, igual muchas gracias por tu tiempo Jheyman